# Difference between rc.conf, loader.conf and static kernel linking in FreeBSD

Tags: kernel, freebsd, kernel-modules, boot-loader, rc

I'm curious:

What, exactly are the benefits to statically linking modules into the kernel rather than loading through rc.conf, etc?

For example:

To add Linux emulation, I could add `linux_enable="YES"` to `/etc/rc.conf`, or I could link it into the kernel by adding `options COMPAT_LINUX` to my kernel config.

Is there actually an advantage to this? If so, what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Statically linking used to be the only way to load a module which is think is the primary reason to having options like COMPAT_LINUX.  Also, prior to `loader`, it used to be the only way to load modules necessary to get FreeBSD to get the necessary drivers to mount the root file system and boot FreeBSD.  Nowadays, I don't think there is any significant benefit to statically linking in a module if it can be easily loaded at runtime.  I don't think you will see any benefit in performance by statically linking Linux compatibility support, but some users still swear by it.  I would avoid it just because of the inconvenience of recompiling a Kernel for little to no perceived performance gain.

Comment: Perfect. It's what I assumed, and I'd *much* rather edit a conf file than recompile whenever I add new support :P

Answer (score 3):

1. If you statically link everything you need you can then simply use `makeoptions NO_MODULES=yes` so you're not building unnecessary modules.

   This can also be accomplished with `MODULES_OVERRIDE` and/or `WITHOUT_MODULES`.
2. The ability to load modules at runtime is not always a good thing. The module could be a rootkit for instance.

   SECURELEVEL also mitigates this.

As with these two, probably any benefit can also (and some would argue, should) be accomplished in another way.

Personally I like my kernel to be like a firewall ruleset: I start by excluding everything, then add what I need and prevent additions at runtime.

Unless the kernel is recompiled, I know exactly what is supported. So if I have not compiled in some functionality, like SCTP or NFS, I can just ignore advisories that only affect those parts. Adding functionality requires me to manually add it.

With modules there are numerous ways how a module could get loaded automatically: by simply using some functionality once, by installing a port, by updating (default changed, new functionality added), etc.

In all of those cases I think it's a benefit to be forced to manually add the functionality if, and only if, it's actually needed.